# Store Text to String[] Arrays?

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0, winrt-component

How can I store data text into string or array in windows store using C#?
I tried this method but it did not work:

```
 string[] phparay ={@"F:\Designe- Video\projects\Phpgonehelp\Phpgonehelp\PHPCODE\Php1.txt"};
```

I thought this would execute any data from text file, but unfortunately it just prints the text path.

Comment: "execute" and "data" somehow contradict each other. May we know how/from where you got the idea that curly braces (`{...}`) somehow enable you to read the content of a file specified by a filename in C#?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper i mean print data BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you'r looking for is this:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\Designe- Video\projects\Phpgonehelp\Phpgonehelp\PHPCODE\Php1.txt");
```

this was taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx

Comment: Thank you , but this method Did not work with Windows store app , As i mention

Comment: What do you mean by not working?  It works just fine for me